# nginX - 301 Redirect a subdomain from multiple domains

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a small web server and am providing email services for a few clients.
They all have their own domains and my mail server is set up at mail.sgenov.com (I am talking about roundcube).
I need to redirect all of their domains to https at mail.sgenov.com,when the subdomain is "mail"
i.e.

```
http://mail.example1.com -> https://mail.sgenov.com
http://mail.blah-123-woohoo.co.uk -> https://mail.sgenov.com
```

This should apply to any current or future domains I might add.
What is the proper way to do this in nginX?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an http server block receive requests for any host name beginning with mail. and redirect those to https://mail.sgenov.com:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mail.*;    
    return 301 https://mail.sgenov.com;
}
```